# Replace regex does not work with sed

Tags: regex, sed

I am trying to replace the number at the end of this : `version=12` containted in the file `config.file`

Here is my script :

```
nbr=13
sed -re "s/version=\d+/$nbr/g" config.file
```

The regex does not seem to detect the number.

Have someone any ideas why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
nbr=13
sed -re "s/(version=)[0-9]+/\1$nbr/g" config.file
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/i0jy5m)

Even if you are using an ERE POSIX regex (enabled with `-r`), you still cannot use PCRE like `\d` digit pattern.

Also, I added a capturing group around `(version=)` to be able to restore it in the replacement part with a `\1` backreference.

Comment: You'll probably way a ^ on the front to avoid replacing `subversion=1` etc.

Comment: @JohnZwinck That is probably a valid remark, but I'd rather remove `g` modifier then, to only enable a single replacement. Let OP decide which is best. I can't see a proof that the string appears at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the explanation, helped me a lot !